# Why can you make ticks across x-axis but not y-axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot you can make ticks cross the x-axis with

`ggplot(mtcars, aes( mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + theme( axis.text = element_blank(), axis.ticks.length.x = unit(c(-.5,.5), "cm"))`

[image: cross-x axis]

The same code for y axis doesn't seem to work. I thought it was a issue with margins but that doesn't seem to be the case.

`ggplot(mtcars, aes( mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + theme( axis.text = element_blank(), axis.ticks.length.y = unit(c(-.5,.5), "cm"))`

[image: y-axis fail]

Comment: works fine for me

Comment: Your code for both the x and y axis work for me. What happens if you just apply the tick marks to both axes at the same time: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + theme(axis.text = element_blank(), axis.ticks.length = unit(c(-.5, .5), "cm"))`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work on my end. Are you using the latest version of ggplot2 and the default theme?

```
update.packages(oldPkgs = "ggplot2")
theme_set(theme_gray())
```

Comment: thanks. I tried that without luck. Just to confirm you get it to work for both x-axis and y-axis?

Comment: Yeah, both are consistent.